# How to modify XML using LINQ to XML ( XDocument)

Tags: .net, linq-to-xml

I have a xml document stored in a file on the server, now i want to modify the same using Linq to Xml.
Here is my code:

```
String strFile = File.ReadAllText(Server.MapPath("~/SessionAnalyserAccessories.xml"));
XDocument xdoc1 = XDocument.Parse(strFile);
xdoc1.XPathSelectElement("SESSIONANALYSER/AP/MODES/NI/STATEINFORMATION/INIT/INPUT/METHOD").AddAfterSelf(new XElement("METHOD", "", new XAttribute("NAME", "Saurabh")));
```

XML Sample i am using, i need to add an element **STATEINFORMATION**:

```
<SESSIONANALYSER>
  <AP>
    <MODES>
      <NI>
        <STATEINFORMATION TYPE="PREPAID">
          <INIT INVALIDINPUTRESPONSE="-2">
            <INPUT VALUE="SLN7ACTIVATION">
              <METHOD NAME="CHECKSUBSCRIBERBALANCE" PARAMETERS="SLN7" POSSIBLEACTIONS="FALLOUTON_FAILUREREGION_SETPSOFAILED_FALSE" MAINTAINSESSION="NO" RESPONSE="-4" NEXTLEVEL="" />
              <METHOD NAME="SETPSOINUCIP" PARAMETERS="SLN7" POSSIBLEACTIONS="FALLOUTON_FAILUREREGION_SETPSOFAILED_FALSE" MAINTAINSESSION="NO" RESPONSE="-4" NEXTLEVEL="" />
            </INPUT>
          </INIT>
        </STATEINFORMATION>
        <STATEINFORMATION TYPE="POSTPAID">
          <INIT INVALIDINPUTRESPONSE="-2">
            <INPUT VALUE="">
              <METHOD NAME="SENDMESSAGE" PARAMETERS="" POSSIBLEACTIONS="FALLOUTONSUCCESS" MAINTAINSESSION="NO" RESPONSE="5" NEXTLEVEL="" />
            </INPUT>
          </INIT>
        </STATEINFORMATION>
      </NI>
    </MODES>
  </AP>
</SESSIONANALYSER>
```

Comment: So, what have you tried?

Comment: If you are looking for tutorials, you might want to search "Linq to Xml" on google.

Comment: @AgentFire, yes i tried using XPath to insert elements, but as my XML hierarchy is very deep(I have other xml files also which are really deep!), so i have to pass the complete hierarchy info of the element i need to insert in the code. Isn't there any automated method where i'd say insert after a certain tag and it'd find one and insert. I am adding the Xpath code to the question as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found some links which contains samples on adding elements through LINQ in XML tree.

Please visit these :-

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387083.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387084.aspx